# MigLayout JTextArea LineWrap is wrapping too soon

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, miglayout

I have a JTextArea that has it's text set to various strings throughout its use. I also have a column that has the dimensions specified as 150!. I want the text to go till the maximum length and then for it wrap. However, right now it is wrapping right away and not going to the maximum length before wrapping. If I add "fill" to the column, then this fixes the issue, however, I don't want to fill up the entire space because I am creating a border. If my text isn't longer then the max, then a bunch of empty space is shown from the border.

Below is an example of how I am doing this.

```
import java.awt.Font;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MigExample extends JFrame {
    public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public static JTextArea content = new JTextArea();
    public static JLabel label;
    public static JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        content.setEditable(false);  
        content.setCursor(null);  
        content.setOpaque(false);  
        content.setFocusable(false);  
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        content.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
        content.setLineWrap(true);
        content.setWrapStyleWord(true);


        String s = "aaaaa bbb ccc ddd e fff ggg hhhhhhhh iiii jjjj kk l mm nnnnn oooooooooo ppppppppppppppp";
        content.setText(s);
        label = new JLabel("Content");
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("",
                "[75!][150!]",
                "[]"));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(content);
        guiFrame.add(panel);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
        guiFrame.setSize(750, 200);

    }

}
```

Comment: don't understand your problem: if you define a layout with a fixed layout width (aka `150!`), you get a layout with a fixed layout width :-) So what do you _really_ want?

Comment: The issue is that I'm not getting a layout for my JTextArea that is 150. It is smaller because of the setLineWrap.